# IndexError at a loop with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup, range

The very famous IndexError. Unfortunately, I really did not find a solution.

The last time visit at the last URL, I always get an error. Whether the website is empty or not. This error occurs whether the range is 2 or 20.

```
    text_file = open("Results-from-{}.txt".format(self.entry_get), "w")

    ### Iterator for end of the url
    multiple_url = []
    for iterator_page in range(15):
            iterator_page = iterator_page + 1
            multiple_url.append("".join([self.sub_url, str(iterator_page)]))

    ### loop for visit all 20 pages ###
    parser = 0
    while parser < len(multiple_url):
        print(multiple_url[parser])
        parser += 1
        with urllib.request.urlopen(multiple_url[parser]) as url:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, "html.parser")

    ### html tag parsing
            names = [name.get_text().strip() for name in soup.findAll("div", {"class": "name m08_name"})]
            street = [address.get_text().strip() for address in soup.findAll(itemprop="streetAddress")]
            plz = [address.get_text().strip() for address in soup.findAll(itemprop="postalCode")]
            city = [address.get_text().strip() for address in soup.findAll(itemprop="addressLocality")]

    ### zip and write
            for line in zip(names, street, plz , city):
                print("%s;%s;%s;%s;\n" % line)
                text_file.write("%s;%s;%s;%s;\n" % line)

    ### output of the path main: cwd_out_final
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    cwd_out = "\{}".format(text_file.name)
    cwd_out_final = cwd + cwd_out


    text_file.close()
```

My Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/x/PycharmProjects/hackday/parser.py", line 55, in search_complete_inner
    with urllib.request.urlopen(multiple_url[parser]) as url:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank You!

Comment: Why do you increment `parser` before opening the url?

Comment: try moving `parser += 1` statement to the end of while loop

Comment: carelessness errors..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You increment `parser` before using it as an index in the `with` statement; doing that on the last element will generate the error in question.  Further, it means you never use the *first* element in the list.